# The PHP don't add the value to an external file

Tags: php, arrays

I write this little script of PHP but when I press the button "Add" it don't add the value to the json.json file, can you tell me what is wrong? The objective is take the values introduced by user on the box add.name and add-link and save it to the json.json file. Have I to call the php script on a html line?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>SSL Checker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/json.json" charset="utf-8"></script>
<?php
$jsonContents = file_get_contents('js/json.json');
$name = $_POST['addname'];
$url = $_POST['addlink'];
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$data[] = array("'name':'.$name.', 'url':'.$url.'");
$json = json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('js/json.json', $jsonString);
?>
</head>
<body onLoad="start()">
    <div id="title">
        <h1>SSL Checker</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="data">
        <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" onsubmit="SSL.Add()">
            <input type="text" name="addname" id="add-name" placeholder="Name"></input>
            <input type="text" name="addlink" id="add-link" placeholder="Link"></input>
            <input type="submit" value="Add">
        </form>
        <div id="edit" role="aria-hidden">
            <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" id="saveEdit">
                <input type="text" id="edit-name">
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" /> <a onclick="CloseInput()" aria-label="Close">&#10006;</a>
            </form>
        </div>
        <p id="counter"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="table">
        <table style="overflow-x:auto;">
            <tr>
                <th>Sites:</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody id="urls">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
function start() {
    var SSL = new function() {
        //List urls to check
        this.el = document.getElementById('urls');
        this.Count = function(data) {
            var el = document.getElementById('counter');
            var name = 'url';

            if (data) {
                if (data > 1) {
                    name = 'urls';
                }
                el.innerHTML = 'There are:' + ' ' + data + ' ' + name;
            } else {
                el.innerHTML = 'No ' + name;
            }
        };
        //Box/Table Configuration (Sites/edit/delete)
        this.FetchAll = function() {
            var data = '';

            if (Checker.length > 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < Checker.length; i++) {
                    data += '<tr>';
                    data += '<td><a href="http://' + Checker[i].url + '">' + Checker[i].name + '</a></td>';
                    data += '<td><button onclick="SSL.Edit(' + i + ')">Edit</button></td>';
                    data += '<td><button onclick="SSL.Delete(' + i + ')">Delete</button></td>';
                    data += '</tr>';

                }
            }

            this.Count(Checker.length);
            return this.el.innerHTML = data;
        };
        //Add name
        this.Add = function() {
            el = document.getElementById('add-name');
            el1 = document.getElementById('add-link')
            var url = el.value;
            var url1 = el1.value;
            if (url) {
                if (url) Checker.push({
                    "name": url,
                    "url": url1
                })
                el.value = '';
                this.FetchAll();
            }
        }

        //Edit
        this.Edit = function(item) {
            var el = document.getElementById('edit-name');
            var el1 = document.getElementById('edit-name1');
            el.value = Checker[item].name;
            el1.value = Checker[item].url;
            document.getElementById('edit').style.display = 'block';
            self = this;
            document.getElementById('saveEdit').onsubmit = function() {
                var url = el.value;
                var url1 = el1.value;
                if (url) {
                    Checker[item].url = url1.trim();
                    Checker[item].name = url.trim();
                    self.FetchAll();
                    CloseInput();
                }
            }
        };
        //Delete
        this.Delete = function(item) {
            Checker.splice(item, 1);
            this.FetchAll();
        };

    };

    SSL.FetchAll();
    //Close button (Edit bar)
    function CloseInput() {
        document.getElementById('edit').style.display = 'none';
    }
    window.CloseInput = CloseInput;
    window.SSL = SSL;
}
```

Comment: What is `SSL.Add()`?

Comment: Its a function of external javascript file (script.js)

Comment: Well you need to include it in your question too.

Comment: you're not using `$jsonContents` in your `json_decode`. Also, `$jsonString` is not a declared variable. Check your `json_encode`

Comment: Please check that where you define the variables: $json & $jsonString

Comment: Check the file permission as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not using your variables in the right way. `json_decode` should use `$jsonContents` and `file_put_contents` should use `$json`

Since you are using post variables, you might want to check if it is a post first.

Try it like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $jsonContents = file_get_contents('js/json.json');
    $name = $_POST['addname'];
    $url = $_POST['addlink'];
    $data = json_decode($jsonContents, true);
    $data[] = array("'name':'.$name.', 'url':'.$url.'");
    $json = json_encode($data);
    file_put_contents('js/json.json', $json);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried your code, but it didn't work, when I introduced The values on Name camp and on Link Camp and I press "Add" it didn't save the value on json.json

Comment: try doing a `var_dump($_POST)` just above the `if` in this answer and tell us if that returns anything, if it doesn't then the problem lies in your form.

Comment: can you do this instead: `var_dump($_POST); die;` to not include any other errors below that line. Still above `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {`

Comment: Do you see any js errors when loading the page or when submitting?

Comment: No, I don't, now when I introduced var_dump($_POST); die; my html page desappear

Comment: That is because of the [die](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php). Are you sure you are allowed to write to the file?

Comment: How can I test it? Hm I think yes, I'm editing it now for do the changes.

Comment: opps sorry shouldn't have added `die` since it's gonna stop your page from loading. Just try the var_dump instead and see if that results in anything. If that shows empty then your form data is not submitted.

Comment: It don't change nothing, I see the same

Comment: Could it be that it isn't called? or it doesn't need be called like js? @hungrykoala

Comment: remove `action="javascript:void(0);" ` from your form and try again. Since the answer posted will update your json file. It's just that your form is not being submitted.

Comment: You could test if the data writes to the file by removing all the javascript and calls and only submit the form.

Comment: Now wrote it but.. ovewrited all content and not add the keys like {
        name:"Yahoo",
        url: "yahoo.com",
    } for example, it add ["'name':'..', 'url':'.gmail.com.'"],

Comment: Yeah it worked @Thefourthbird but now it overwrite all and it don't save the "name" value